# sprintf with format in C++

Tags: c++, string, printf

I'm learning C++ while I'm coding and now I have doubt:
I have this code:

```
std::string cstr;
double searchEquinox;

sprintf(cstr, "B%7.2f", searchEquinox);
```

Reading on Internet I have found that I have to use `std::ostringstream`, but my problem is that I don't how to 'translate' `B%7.2f` using `std::ostringstream`.

```
std::ostringstream out;  
out << searchEquinox;
cstr = out.str();
```

What do I have to do to get the same output using `std::ostringstream`?

Comment: You cannot pass a `std::string` object as the buffer pointer for `sprintf()` to write into.  You would have to preallocate the `std::string` first and then you can pass `&cstr[0]` as the buffer pointer.  But `std::ostringstream` is the correct way to handle this in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [input/output manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip):

```
#include <iomanip>

// ...

std::ostringstream out;  
out << "B" << std::fixed << std::setw(7) << std::setprecision(2) << searchEquinox;
```